# How to set this permalink structure in WordPress: /custom-taxonomy/custom-post-type/post-name

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I'm coding a WordPress website for a festival that takes place in several cities.
My custom post type is `events` and the custom taxonomy is `city`.

I would like to have a permalink structure like this:

`festival.com/city/events/event-name`

Comment: To help others help you, please mention what CMS you are using.

Comment: Thanks @MitchellK, just edited